# Switch Ethernet and WiFi automatically, using the same IP Address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8, ethernet

I have a service on my phone that backups data on my Windows8 PC.
The PC can be connected to the private network via Ethernet or Wireless and the PC should be always reachable from my service (via hostname possibly).

I have some problems:

- My Android (my MacBook behave the same) resolves the IP, but if I switch to Ethernet **my backup service keeps trying to connect to the previous WiFi IP**. Can't understand if it is a network (ARP cache?) problem and how to solve it.
- As a solution I thought to configure the **same IP address for both the PC WiFi and Ethernet adapters** so that no matter what the resolved IP is always correct. But Windows seems to go crazy every time that I do it (while it should be supported by any SO).
- I don't want to remember all the times to disconnect one network once I connect the other. I'd like to set the **WiFi to be excluded when the Ethernet is plugged**.

Are these issues resolvable on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear how your current setup works. If you're using a DNS name it might be cached and outdated when you switch.

Depending on how the backup software works, there are three basic approaches.

1. Set up the DNS name to resolve to both addresses and deactivate dynamic DNS updates. Leave it to the software to select the currently working IP address. If names are resolved by broadcast instead of a DNS server this won't work.
2. Configure the same, static IP address for both Ethernet and wireless NICs. Do not activate both connections simultaneously. You'll have to switch back to DHCP if you need to connect to other networks though.
3. Configure the Ethernet NIC's MAC address onto the wireless NIC (or vice versa), so that the DHCP server will issue the same IP address for both connections. You might need to set up a DHCP reservation for this to work reliably.

If you can't/don't want to switch over manually, this can also be scripted in `netsh`.